# IE as browser-control, equivalent on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit, dhtml

On Windows it's possilble to use IE as a browser-control in .NET. So you can use a webpage as UI and write the code in C#, VB or C++ accessing the DOM. Is this possible on a Mac too? Of course it would be Webkit(Safari) and Objective-C. Or even better: Can you use JavaScript to access the platform (like WinRT in Windows 8)?

Comment: You certainly *can* do that, but it's far easier to simply lay out a real Aqua UI in a nib, and you get a ton of stuff (accessibility, tabbability, sliders, etc.) for free that you wouldn't by writing HTML. If you already have a web page that you can (or need to) reuse, then that may be a win, but I'd strongly urge you to consider making a real native UI—it really is easy.